# Could not symlink share/git-core/contrib /usr/local/share/git-core is not writable

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I've really tried and used any suggestion from repairing, over uninstalling everything, to reinstalling, etc. but no solution works. I'm completely stuck and need help to find a solution! Thanks in advance, Christoph

```
MacBook-2:~ MyUserName$ brew install git
Warning: git-2.1.3 already installed, it's just not linked
MacBook-2:~ MyUserName$ brew destroy git
Error: Unknown command: destroy
MacBook-2:~ MyUserName$ brew uninstall git
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.1.3...
MacBook-2:~ MyUserName$ brew install git
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-    2.1.3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-2.1.3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring git-2.1.3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
 /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The 'contrib' directory has been installed to:
 /usr/local/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
 /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/git-core/contrib
 /usr/local/share/git-core is not writable.

You can try again using:
 brew link git
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.1.3: 1342 files, 32M
MacBook-2:~ MyUserName$ brew link git
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.1.3... 
Error: Could not symlink share/git-core/contrib
 /usr/local/share/git-core is not writable.
```

Answer (score 29):

This is probably an error related to permissions.

Try

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/
```

or, if you only need this on the git-core path,

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/git-core
```

might be enough.

Then run

```
brew link git
```

again.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help either.... Terminal tells me then:

    Christophs-MacBook-2:~ AWChristoph$ brew link git
    Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git

Comment: Seems to be the same issue there, then. Do a `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar/`.

Comment: @matthias Apparently not, it tells me

    Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.1.3... Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.2

Comment: @AWChristoph: I think you kind of miss the point of what we're doing with the chown -R. Every time you stumble upon a new _permission denied_ message, that is because the user who is currently running the `brew` command does not have permission to write to those directories. With that said, for this newest message you posted, you need to do `chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/perl5/`. But maybe it would be easier to just do `sudo brew link git`. Though, this is normally not recommended.

Comment: The problem is that I receive this errors

chown: /usr/local/lib/perl5//site_perl/Git/I18N.pm: Operation not permitted
chown: /usr/local/lib/perl5//site_perl/Git/IndexInfo.pm: Operation not permitted
chown: /usr/local/lib/perl5//site_perl/Git/SVN/Editor.pm: Operation not permitted.... -> and more of them

Comment: Oh, put a `sudo` infront of it. In all cases where you need to change permissions of a directory which is not owned by current user, you need to do `sudo`. So, `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/perl5/` should do the trick for ya.

Comment: I'm running ZSH, for me it was: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`.

Comment: @DevinBrown: Instead of `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/` or `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/git-core` ? I'll update the answer to also comply with ZSH.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you use `sudo` to install some application before ,So the owner of dictionary `/usr/local/share/` and `/usr/local/lib` become `root`

run:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
```

and then run:

```
brew link git
```

Comment: He tell me :    No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git

Answer (score 0):

**Before changing permissions I would:**

**Option 1: Try to Uninstall brew**

1 ) Save a list of your brew packages:

```
brew list > my_packages.txt
```

2 ) Then [uninstall brew](https://superuser.com/questions/203707/how-to-uninstall-homebrew):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

3 ) [Re-install brew](https://brew.sh/#install):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

4 ) Re-install all your packages:

```
brew install $(< my_packages.txt )
```

**Option 2:**

If that didn't work try running:

```
brew doctor
```

Check if errors can be pruned with:

```
brew prune
```

---

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784545/brew-error-could-not-symlink-path-is-not-writable).