# Brew error: Could not symlink, path is not writable

Tags: package, homebrew

When I try to install a library with **homebrew** (`brew install aLibrary`), I got the following error:

```
Could not symlink lib/pkgconfig/aFile
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable.
```

What should I do?

*There are several questions and answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449581/brew-install-libyaml-error),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable),etc.) concerning this brew error, this is an attempt to make a general question as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31712/262501).*

Answer (score 168, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15628268/719276) by [Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275065/rick):

Start with `brew doctor` which will show you errors with your brew setup.

You might see something like this: "Warning: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable."

It will give you the advice that: "You should probably chown /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig".

This means:   `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

Then you will need to link the files with this: `brew link yourLibrary`

If this does not work hopefully the output of `brew doctor` will give you enough to continue the search.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` seems a great copy paste answer.

Comment: I had 2 folders that needed this action. Running `brew doctor` and then copying the suggested command from there is even better.

Comment: But why does brew need access to something that it doesn't have by default? What is the purpose of that dir and why should i go out of my way to give extra access to brew?

Answer (score 12):

Giant Elk had a great suggestion and this is how I fixed my issue, which in my opinion is the cleanest. Users should not change permissions unless they know the ramifications.

1. Output your installed packages (via brew) to a text file:

   ```
   brew list > brewlist.txt
   ```
2. Uninstall brew:

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
   ```
3. Re-install brew:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
4. Re-install previous packages (edit list if you do not need all packages):

   ```
   brew install $(< brewlist.txt )
   ```

Comment: Am doing this now, and perhaps 2. and 3. could be updated since I got the messages:

Warning: The Ruby Homebrew installer is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Comment: and for uninstall:

Warning: The Ruby Homebrew uninstaller is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"

Comment: Also, step 4 can very likely fail for one item, and then fails the whole thing.  So I ended up having to install each one individually, which of course takes more time.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following.

```
$ brew doctor
```

message will display error links to prune. If any found, run next option.

```
$ brew prune
```

once these are removed, proceed to link them agian

```
$ brew link python
```

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled brew, re-installed, then the issues went away.

Answer (score 3):

You should simply give the permission to your account by running this command on terminal.

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) (path)`

In your case:
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) lib/pkgconfig/aFile /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`